# Text boxes inside EmptyDataTemplate not accessible

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, code-behind, emptydatatext

I have an ASP.NET GridView that uses an EmptyDataTemplate. Inside EmptyDataTemplate i am having some text boxes and a submit button for the insertion of records. When I try to access the ID's in the code behind file they are not showing up.

My code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White"
        BorderColor="#DEDFDE" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="Black"
        GridLines="Vertical">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="BankName" HeaderText="Bank Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="IFSCCode" HeaderText="IFSC Code" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="MICRCODE" HeaderText="MICR Code" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="BranchName" HeaderText="Branch Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Address" HeaderText="Address" />
        </Columns>
        <EmptyDataTemplate>
            <div style="border: 1px solid #ccc; width: auto; margin: 20px 470px;">
                <table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="3" bgcolor="#1e7c9a" style="color: White">
                            Please Enter Your Bank Details
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Bank Name
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtBankname" runat="server" Width="180px" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" ErrorMessage="Required"
                                ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="txtBankname" runat="server" Width="120" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            IFSC Code
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtIfsccode" runat="server" Width="180px" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                           <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" ErrorMessage="Required"
                                ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="txtIfsccode" runat="server" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            MICR Code
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtMicrcode" runat="server" Width="180px" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            &nbsp;
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Branch Name
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtBranchName" runat="server" Width="180px" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                           <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" ErrorMessage="Required"
                                Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="txtBranchName" runat="server" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Address
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddress" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" ErrorMessage="Required"
                                ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="txtAddress" runat="server" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Button ID="btn" Text="Submit" runat="server" OnClick="InsertDetails"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </EmptyDataTemplate>
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCC99" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#1e7c9a" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#CE5D5A" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FBFBF2" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#848384" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#EAEAD3" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#575357" />
    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: if you use Visible=False  for the controls remove it and use css rule display:none.

Comment: I want to get the values from the TextBoxes inside EmptyDataTemplate and insert a new record into my data base. My problem is ID aren't accessible in the code behind.

Comment: can u share the code behind function

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
Button Insert_Details = gv.Controls[0].Controls[0].FindControl("btn") as Button ;
```

You can see this **[EXAMPLE](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/424661/Access-Controls-from-ASP-NET-GridView-EmptyDataTem)**

Comment: Thank you. It really helped. What is did id below:

TextBox BankName = gv.Controls[0].Controls[0].FindControl("txtBankname") as TextBox;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BankName", BankName.Text );
                TextBox IFSCcode = gv.Controls[0].Controls[0].FindControl("txtIfsccode") as TextBox;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IFSCcode", IFSCcode.Text);

Comment: good luck :) if this was useful to you.could you accept this as answer or up vote this answer

Answer (score 0):

*Solution by OP.*

Done it as below:

```
TextBox BankName = gv.Controls[0].Controls[0].FindControl("txtBankname") as TextBox;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BankName", BankName.Text );
TextBox IFSCcode = gv.Controls[0].Controls[0].FindControl("txtIfsccode") as TextBox;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IFSCcode", IFSCcode.Text);
TextBox MICROCODE = gv.Controls[0].Controls[0].FindControl("txtMicrcode") as TextBox;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MICROCODE",MICROCODE.Text);
TextBox BranchName = gv.Controls[0].Controls[0].FindControl("txtBranchName") as     TextBox;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BranchName",BranchName.Text);
TextBox BankAddress = gv.Controls[0].Controls[0].FindControl("txtAddress") as TextBox;
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BankAddress", BankAddress.Text);
```